# How can I implement ReorderableList on a PropertyDrawer when the property is the list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I created a `ForceCaseAttribute` which is planned to work on arrays of strings, lists of strings as well as on plain strings, however I cannot seem to figure out how to properly display the `ReorderableList` my current code for the drawer is as follows

```
public override void OnGUI ( Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label ) {
    ForceCaseAttribute fca = attribute as ForceCaseAttribute;
    ReorderableList list = new ReorderableList ( property.serializedObject, property, true, true, true, true );
    list.drawHeaderCallback = ( Rect rect ) => {
        EditorGUI.LabelField ( rect, label );
    };
    list.drawElementCallback = ( Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused ) => {
        SerializedProperty element = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex ( index );
        string e = element.stringValue;
        e = EditorGUI.TextField ( rect, e );
        element.stringValue = fca.LetterCase == LetterCase.Lower ? e.ToLower () : fca.LetterCase == LetterCase.Upper ? e.ToUpper () : fca.LetterCase == LetterCase.Pascal ? Pascal ( e ) : Pascal ( e.Split ( new char [] { ' ' } ) );
    };
    list.DoLayoutList ();
}
```

but it displays in the inspector as this

[image: Each 'Element' of my initial list displays as a list that cannot be added to.]

Each of the fields labelled with Element # cannot be added to, and are parented by the initial list and none of this is throwing any errors. Is there some major step that I am missing in order to be able to correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After a short break I came back and tried something unusual. As it turns out if you put an attribute before a List or an array of strings, then attempt to create a property drawer for that attribute, it creates a property drawer for a single element and applies it to each. I'm not sure why this happens but it's what works.

```
public override void OnGUI ( Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label ) {
    ForceCaseAttribute fca = attribute as ForceCaseAttribute;
    string e = property.stringValue;
    e = EditorGUI.TextField ( position, label, e );
    property.stringValue = fca.LetterCase == LetterCase.Lower ? e.ToLower () : fca.LetterCase == LetterCase.Upper ? e.ToUpper () : fca.LetterCase == LetterCase.Pascal ? Pascal ( e ) : Pascal ( e.Split ( new char [] { ' ' } ) );
}
```

Comment: Yes this is known to be the case ;) attributes on lists apply to the elements, not the list itself

Comment: @derHugo I just wish I'd found that information somewhere, because I had no idea and I spent several hours trying to figure this very problem out before I realized that.